# MS Access 2016 won't open an .accdb file because it 'was created in a previous version'. Is there a fix?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

We are testing existing MS Access DBs with Access 2016. Some DBs were set up to use Workgroups. Given the age of the DBs, I assume they were created in Access 97. During previous upgrades, they were converted to the 'Access 2000-2003'format. This format should be compatible with MS Access 2016, but it refused to open the files with the message 'Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application'. I opened the DBs in Access 2007, and converted them to that format (from .mdb to .accdb), but MS Access 2016 continues to report 'Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application'. Has anyone any suggestions?

Many thanks, Kevin

Comment: I could open mdb's with Access 2000 format in Access 2016. Make sure to not only convert the front-end but the back-end as well (there may be tables linked to another mdb (the back-end).

Comment: Thanks Olivier, you're right, these DBs are linked to backend databases. The backend databases have been upgraded along with the frontends as we've deployed upgrades of MS Access. The backends are acting in the same way, i.e. Access 2016 refuses to open them in 2000-2003 (.mdb) format or 2007 (.accdb) format.

Comment: See: [Convert a database to the .accdb file format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098DDD31-5F84-4E89-8F44-DB0CF7C11ACD)

Comment: I'm going to post a separate question regarding this, but in case anyone comes across this thread, the workgroup files associated with some of these databases did not get updated at the same time as the frontend and backend databases. If I open the workgroup files themselves directly, they are showing as Access '95. They are also encoded, which is preventing me from updating their format.

Comment: Note that there are even older formats. If the format is older than Acc 97, you will have to use an older Access Application (e.g. Acc 2000) and to first convert the very old format to Acc 2000. Then Acc 2016 can convert this format to an accdb.

Comment: Thanks again Olivier, I was worried that that might be the case, as currently I only have access to Access 2007. Once we realised that the problems we were experiencing ultimately originated in the .mdw files, we changed tack and are now trying to update those files, to continue with .mdb and .mdw in 2016. Today I've made progress of sorts, in that I discovered that I could use the greyed-out 'Save as' option (rather than 'Convert') to get a 2003 file, then rename the resultant .mdb back to .mdw, but there are issues related to MSysAccessObjects, and basically the usernames are not valid.

Comment: (ran out of space). Converting didn't work because the .mdw was encrypted, and 'Decrypt' was greyed out. I've picked up a few tips regarding .mdw file manipulation (compressing, stripping rights from the Admin user) to see how far I get, but at the back of my mind I suspect that I'll ultimately need to look into Access 2000, as you suggested. Thanks for commenting! :-)

Comment: Sorry, meant files are 'Encoded' and 'Decode' is greyed-out